# DataB and DataB-copy worked on simultaniously - how merge DataB-copy into DataB

Tags: arcgis-10.0, database

ArcGis 10 - EDITED (sorry for not being more specific, quite new to the arcgis world)

We need to enter A LOT of Map data (Sewage system) into a Database in a relatively short time. It involves an area of about 14km^2 with pipes, manholes (couple hundred) and relvant buildings. All of which have numerous attributes. These are cataloged in 30 some feature classes. Data entered via scans that are georeferenced and then copied by hand via ArcMap. I assume that they're ESRI-feature classes [ArcCatalog says "Personal-Geodatabase Feature-Class"]. 
The database (.mdb file) is about 130mb.

Following idea:
Database "A" is main Database. A copy is made "A-copy".
With two liscenses two people can work on A simultaneously (different areas).

After a certain time, we want to import all the entered data from "A-copy" back into "A".
How would one best attempt to do this this without overwriting the changes made in "A" during this time?

(the entered data is as good as idependant from the data already entered; It would be possible to wipe all tables from "A-copy" before starting)

Both users would ideally be accesing and entering data into the same tables. [Maybe it would be possible to limit that to a certain extent, not quite sure how topo-lines owuld react if e.g. one user placed all the manholes in one area and then on the next day a second person would connect them in the copy-db and then transfer the pipe feature-class back into the original.]
From what I can tell sde is not in use; we have no possibility of multi-user simultaneous access to this particular database. Is there a way to qickly check this?
I didn't set up the system and am not versed in doing that either.

This wouldn't have to happen on a daily basis, so a multistep process would be still be feasable.

Thanks a million

Comment: replication. To give a better answer we need more information. Are these esri feature classes? Is it an ent gdb or file, hopefully not personal?  Is sde in use? Are users editing ALL tables?  How much is A LOT? # tables, Size of db? The question part of your question is not very clear. please state a clear question and make the title reflect that.

Comment: What do you mean with "ent gdb or file, hopefully not personal"? ArcCatalog "Personal-Geodatabase Feature-Class" answer that? :-/

Comment: i dont know arcgis, but i think you need prober database like Oracle or PostgreSQL or MS SQL which shares data to all clients

Comment: It just depends on your programming prowess. The ent gdb, (enterprise geodatabase), the ones simplexio mentioned have solution for what you want. File gdb would be very difficult to implement. But it has probably been done. Personal gdb I wouldn't spend the time to try on it.  It is too susceptible to corruption, especially with everything you are wanting to do.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your input. Will probably just have to work in shifts then. Thanks